# How to add Google Barcode to android app inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, barcode, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I'm new in the android world and i'm trying how to integrate https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android instead inside of an activity i need it inside a fragment.

So the user should press the button scan_btn and then open the camera ready to scan the barcode, thanks a lot.

```
package com.example.navbartrack.ui.gallery;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.navbartrack.R;

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
    private Button scan_btn;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        galleryViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);

        scan_btn = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /*Open camera and get photo*/
            }
        });


        return root;
    }

    /**
     * Method to get photo
     */

    /**
     * Method to get info
     */

    


}
```

Comment: Integrating ML Kit inside Fragment is essentially similar to do it in Activity.

Have you checked ML Kit demo app?
https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart

Or do you have some specific questions that fragment related?

Comment: Yes i've already checked, but i see nowhere is implemented inside a fragment and i was curious about it.

Comment: Yeah, ML Kir demos don't have samples for Fragment, but I think you can check CameraX sample and integrate ML Kit in this method. https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L639

Comment: Yeah thanks i'll try in that way, zxing library works perfectly with fragment, i hope to find a way in the future for google ml in a fragment.